# JAX RPC Stub issue with XSD complex type

Tags: xsd, wsdl, websphere, jax-ws, jax-rpc

I've a WSDL XSD with request & response complex type elements defined.

```
  <xsd:complexType name="authPartyRequest">
       <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Party" type="ICI-CAAS:Party" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xsd:element name="Address" type="ICI-CAAS:Address" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:complexType>


  <xsd:complexType name="authPartyResponse">
       <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="Channel" type="ICI-CAAS:Channel" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xsd:element name="Event" type="ICI-CAAS:Event" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
          <xsd:element name="Party" type="ICI-CAAS:Party" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:complexType>
```

and WSDL has portType definition including

```
   <wsdl:operation name="authenticateParty">
       <wsdl:input message="ICI-CAAS:authPartyRequst" />
       <wsdl:output message="ICI-CAAS:authPartyResponse" />  --> method response type
   </wsdl:operation>
```

When I generate the stubs using JAX-RPC (with WAS 6.1 run time) I'm seeing port type interface is generated with operation having response as 'void'. How ever I see request parameter is passed correctly.

```
  public interface AuthManagerService_PortType extends java.rmi.Remote
  {
   public void authenticateParty(AuthPartyRequest req); --> generating response type 'void'
  }
```

Can any one please help on priority?

Comment: Why don't you paste the full WSDL.

Comment: Unless you had a copy and paste error, I would have expected the opposite result, an operation with a return type but no input parameter because you have a typo in the declaration of your wsdl:input, "<wsdl:input message="ICI-CAAS:authPartyRequst" />", request is misspelled.